# Can someone provide me a logstash filter for auth.log in linux?

Tags: logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-grok, elk

**This kind of log:**
(I need a grok pattern to extarct the IP and user... And i want check it whether it is a password failure.)

```
Sep 18 15:54:25 amantha-server-ubuntu sshd[4692]: Received disconnect from 192.168.3.198 port 34222:11: disconnected by user
    Sep 18 15:54:25 amantha-server-ubuntu sshd[4692]: Disconnected from user amantha 192.168.3.198 port 34222
    Sep 18 15:54:25 amantha-server-ubuntu sshd[4612]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user amantha
    Sep 18 15:54:25 amantha-server-ubuntu systemd-logind[673]: Session 13 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
    Sep 18 15:54:25 amantha-server-ubuntu systemd-logind[673]: Removed session 13.
    Sep 18 15:54:30 amantha-server-ubuntu sshd[4726]: Accepted password for amantha from 192.168.3.198 port 34226 ssh2
    Sep 18 15:54:30 amantha-server-ubuntu sshd[4726]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user amantha by (uid=0)
    Sep 18 15:54:30 amantha-server-ubuntu systemd-logind[673]: New session 14 of user amantha.
    Sep 18 15:55:22 amantha-server-ubuntu sshd[4823]: Accepted password for amantha from 192.168.3.198 port 34232 ssh2
    Sep 18 15:55:22 amantha-server-ubuntu sshd[4823]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user amantha by (uid=0)
    Sep 18 15:55:22 amantha-server-ubuntu systemd-logind[673]: New session 15 of user amantha.
    Sep 18 15:55:31 amantha-server-ubuntu sshd[4904]: Received disconnect from 192.168.3.198 port 34232:11: disconnected by user
    Sep 18 15:55:31 amantha-server-ubuntu sshd[4904]: Disconnected from user amantha 192.168.3.198 port 34232
    Sep 18 15:55:31 amantha-server-ubuntu sshd[4823]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user amantha
    Sep 18 15:55:31 amantha-server-ubuntu systemd-logind[673]: Session 15 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
    Sep 18 15:55:31 amantha-server-ubuntu systemd-logind[673]: Removed session 15.
    Sep 18 15:55:37 amantha-server-ubuntu sshd[4938]: Accepted password for amantha from 192.168.3.198 port 34244 ssh2
    Sep 18 15:55:37 amantha-server-ubuntu sshd[4938]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user amantha by (uid=0)
    Sep 18 15:55:37 amantha-server-ubuntu systemd-logind[673]: New session 16 of user amantha.
    Sep 18 16:04:43 amantha-server-ubuntu su: pam_unix(su-l:session): session closed for user root
    Sep 18 16:04:43 amantha-server-ubuntu sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
    Sep 18 16:05:17 amantha-server-ubuntu sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
    Sep 18 16:05:19 amantha-server-ubuntu sudo: pam_unix(sudo:auth): Couldn't open /etc/securetty: No such file or directory
    Sep 18 16:05:19 amantha-server-ubuntu sudo:  amantha : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/home/amantha ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/su -
    Sep 18 16:05:19 amantha-server-ubuntu sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by amantha(uid=0)
    Sep 18 16:05:19 amantha-server-ubuntu su: (to root) amantha on pts/0
    Sep 18 16:05:19 amantha-server-ubuntu su: pam_unix(su-l:session): session opened for user root by amantha(uid=0)
```

Comment: Could you please provide a log line for password failure scenario ?

Comment: You can get the IP with `%{IP:ip}`. Though it won't match with all lines.